# Please modify the front page algorithm to demote closed questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

Lets face it, our question volume isn't all that high.  This means that questions tend to hang around on the front page for a while, either good or bad.  In particular I've noticed that closed questions are just hanging out there for a while.  This is somewhat unsightly.

**Please adjust the algorithm to keep closed questions away from the front page, or at least not at the top.**

Answer (score 4):

Rather than adjust the closure decay, I'd prefer to focus on the root of the issue and simply work on ways to increase question volume so the algorithm functions normally.  We already have topics to work on boosting activity.  The algorithm may have to be tweaked again when/if the site achieves a defined 'normal' level of activity if a custom solution were implemented.

Answer (score 3):

**I disagree.**

They seem to decay significantly faster than other questions as it is now.  If they don't stay on the front page for a bit, their odds of getting a fair chance at being reopened drop.

Answer (score -1):

Please consider that when *I* revisited a question a few months after my initial reply (after having both reconsidered and also received related input from others not on SE), I was eviscerated by the users AND moderators. (That treatment of course decreased my participation here, which seemed to be the intent of the mods.)

Since revisiting a question can be so hazardous, why do you want to encourage it? :(

Comment: What question was this?